# How do I allow the "+" and "()" in my trappings for numbers only to be entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current code right now, I can only enter integers. What I want to do is to add the "+" and the parenthesis "()". How can I adjust my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".numeric").keydown(function (event) {
        var num = event.keyCode;
        if ((num>  95 && num < 106) || (num > 36 && num < 41) || num == 9) {
           return;
         }
        if (event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.altKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (num != 46 && num != 8) {
            if (isNaN(parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.which)))) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: How did you work out the code for the numbers? Why can't you do the same process?

Comment: check this reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From table reference -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent :

```
DOM_VK_OPEN_PAREN   0xA8 (168)  Open parenthesis ("(") key.
DOM_VK_CLOSE_PAREN  0xA9 (169)  Close parenthesis (")") key.
DOM_VK_PLUS         0xAB (171)  Plus ("+") key.
```

So your check will be:

```
if ((num>  95 && num < 106) || (num > 36 && num < 41) || num == 9 || (num >=  168 && num <= 169) || num == 171)
```

---

**EDIT:**

With some help, I eventually created regular expression to work for these requirements:

http://jsfiddle.net/elen/R8M7K/7/

code:

```
$(".numeric").keydown(function (event) {
    var num = event.keyCode;
    if(event.shiftKey) num = 's_'+num;
    var pattern2 = new RegExp(/^(9[6-9]|10[0-5]|3[7-9]|40|9|s_57|s_48|171|107|s_187|)$/);
    if ( pattern2.test(num) ){
        return;
    }
    if (event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.altKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (num != 46 && num != 8) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.which)))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI when not dealing with ranges you can shorten the code with regex, for example, the end of the code example above could be: `/^(9|168|169|171)$/.test(num)`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes very good, but unfortunately I'm not very good at regex =) the best I could come up to try to cover all above checks is `/^(9|168|169|171|[0-9\(\)\+])+$/` but this doesn't work for `(`,`)` when pressing `Shift` key. If you can improve it, I will add to my answer.

Comment: The brackets are already covered by `168|169` - it would just be `if ( (num>  95 && num < 106) || (num > 36 && num < 41) || /^(9|168|169|171)$/.test(num) )`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP no, this does not allow `()+`.... http://jsfiddle.net/R8M7K/ - I kind of hoped to improve it to regex completely...

Comment: @SmokeyPHP still `+` doesn't work on either... =) and with `pattern2.test(num)` - no input from num pad on the right hand side. It looks like my simple first provided solution is the best...

Comment: [jsfiddle works for all](http://jsfiddle.net/R8M7K/4/) - forgot about the plus =/ and numpad works for me with both, have you enabled numlock?

Comment: Aaanyway, doesn't really matter, just wanted to note that simple collections of `num=9 or num=171 or num=12 etc...` could be `/9|171|12/` for simplicity

Comment: This is still not working for me kind sirs, I think the problem is because of the fact that it has a combination of two key presses to make a + sign? What do you think?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP , @Jessica Roberts - regular expresion - `/^(9[6-9]|10[0-5]|3[7-9]|40|9|s_57|s_48|171|107|s_187|)$/` - I have updated my answer